# Как сделать проект из одного .cpp файла?

Tags: c++

Сколько уже пробовал, и видео смотрел - не выходит.
Нужно сделать проект, где есть main.cpp и файлы с .h
И есть еще баг с тем, что ввести могу только англ значения, кириллица потом не выводится.
Сам код: https://ideone.com/BDAOfQ

Файлы проекта:

```
Base.cpp - https://ideone.com/cTEq00

Base.h - https://ideone.com/n3lW71

main.cpp - https://ideone.com/CQ4LG6
```

Ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Среда разработки?

Comment: для кириллицы: `setlocale(LC_ALL, "");` в начале `main`

Comment: Общая проблема в том, что видимо вы плохо знакомы с языком и ООП, ведь в каждом методе функции вы вводите лишние переменные. Помимо этого, есть ненужные значения с одинаковыми именами, поэтому компилятор ругается на повторения.

Comment: @a_nR1085__i не работает setlocate

Comment: Даже не глядя в файлы - наверняка в .h-файл поместили определение функции/переменной `r`, `a`, `file`...

Answer (score 1):

Открываем `base.h` и видим:

```
const char* file = "jurnal";
char a[256];
char* r(char* b)
{
    CharToOem(b, a);
    return a;
}
```

QED. Вы поместили в заголовочный файл определения переменных и функции, и в результате в каждом .cpp-файле получаете переменную/функцию с одним и тем же именем и приводите к нарушению правила ODR (one definition rule).

Если используемый компилятор позволяет - можно дописать `inline` и снять проблему, если нет - переменные объявить (не определить) с помощью ключевого слова `extern`, а определить в одном из .cpp-файлов. От функции оставить только объявление, определение вынести в .cpp-файл.

Это по ошибкам. Предупреждения связаны с тем, что вы объявляете переменную, которую не используете.

```
void Base::redac()
{
    system("cls");
    int t = 0;
```

`t` нигде дальше не используется. Формально это не ошибка.